# startActivityForResult show how to work the alternative

Tags: android

I know this is a very old topic and I tried to solve it alone for about a week with no luck. As you figure out I am nub in this most background is plc and microcontrollers. Any way. I am posting the code whole for your help and I would like if someone has the time to show me in practice how I have to do it. I read a lot and watch videos but in practice no result is probably something I am getting wrong because of my limited knowledge.
Thank you for your time.
P.S of course code is not mine I am just trying to start with some code that I can understand a little more than others.

`

```
package com.example.bluetooth.btmessenger2;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`enter code here`
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Ardcon extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String MODULE_MAC = "98:D3:34:90:6F:A1";
    public final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    BluetoothAdapter bta;
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    ConnectedThread btt = null;
    Button switchLight, switchRelay;
    TextView response;
    boolean lightflag = false;
    boolean relayFlag = true;
    public Handler mHandler;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ardcon);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating listeners");
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);
        switchRelay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.relay);
        switchLight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchlight);

        switchLight.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Attempting to send data");
            if (mmSocket.isConnected() && btt != null) { //if we have connection to the bluetoothmodule
                if (!lightflag) {
                    String sendtxt = "LY";
                    btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                    lightflag = true;
                } else {
                    String sendtxt = "LN";
                    btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                    lightflag = false;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Ardcon.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        switchRelay.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Attempting to send data");
            if (mmSocket.isConnected() && btt != null) { //if we have connection to the bluetoothmodule
                if(relayFlag){
                    String sendtxt = "RY";
                    btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                    relayFlag = false;
                }else{
                    String sendtxt = "RN";
                    btt.write(sendtxt.getBytes());
                    relayFlag = true;
                }

                //disable the button and wait for 4 seconds to enable it again
                switchRelay.setEnabled(false);
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        return;
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(() -> switchRelay.setEnabled(true));

                }).start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Ardcon.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //if bluetooth is not enabled then create Intent for user to turn it on
        if(!bta.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }else{
            initiateBluetoothProcess();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            initiateBluetoothProcess();
        }
    }

    public void initiateBluetoothProcess(){

        if(bta.isEnabled()){

            //attempt to connect to bluetooth module
            BluetoothSocket tmp;
            mmDevice = bta.getRemoteDevice(MODULE_MAC);

            //create socket
            try {
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                mmSocket = tmp;
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]","Connected to: "+mmDevice.getName());
            }catch(IOException e){
                try{mmSocket.close();}catch(IOException c){return;}
            }

            Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating handler");
            mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //super.handleMessage(msg);
                    if(msg.what == ConnectedThread.RESPONSE_MESSAGE){
                        String txt = (String)msg.obj;
                        if(response.getText().toString().length() >= 30){
                            response.setText("");
                            response.append(txt);
                        }else{
                            response.append("\n" + txt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Log.i("[BLUETOOTH]", "Creating and running Thread");
            btt = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket,mHandler);
            btt.start();


        }
    }

}
`
```

I followed your steps and now is ok the code compiling with no errors. I install it on my phone. Installation comes back successful then comes up the permission request for the BT answer yes then i have the confirmation the screen comes up as she should. After a i asume is looking for the mac address and then stops. From the logcat comes these: 2021-12-18 17:02:02.471 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null

2021-12-18 17:02:02.471 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback

2021-12-18 17:02:02.481 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[61]}

2021-12-18 17:02:08.921 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon I/[BLUETOOTH]: Creating handler

2021-12-18 17:02:08.921 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon I/[BLUETOOTH]: Creating and running Thread

2021-12-18 17:02:08.921 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon I/[THREAD-CT]: Creating thread

2021-12-18 17:02:08.921 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null

2021-12-18 17:02:08.931 16147-16147/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null

2021-12-18 17:02:08.951 16147-16340/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon I/[THREAD-CT]: Starting thread

2021-12-18 17:02:09.041 16147-16340/com.example.bluetooth.ardcon A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 16340 (Thread-938)

The bold last lines are the fault and red. Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start the activity, you can use the below code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

To get the result, you can put this code and inside that, you can get the result. You have to put this method global into your class.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = 
        registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    initiateBluetoothProcess();
                }
            }
        });
```

For more details, you can read [Document for ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java)

Comment: Found out that there is actually a side-effect when using it like this. It will automatically retriever the flow when the component is resumed.